# Socket IO socket properties are not saved

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I am using NodeJS with SocketIO. 
When I assign property in async function, like this

```
socket.on(channel, (data) => {socket.username = "username" });
```

and after that use this property in some other place. (in another socket.on callback function), I get the message that socket.username is undefined.

I also create a var username separately, but the result is the same. The assigned value is not visible in the outer function.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You need to post more context.

Answer (score 0):

Every socket connection has it's own context.

If You want to share data between contexts - You've to keep it in place that can be globally accessible.

There are many ways to achieve it.

Simple of them is following:

1) Create a module `GlobalContext` with following content:

```
module.exports = new Map();
```

2) And pass Your context variables like this:

```
const context = require('./GlobalContext');

socket.on(channel, (data) => {
  context.set('username', "someone"); 
});
```

3) Access to it from outside:

```
const context = require('./GlobalContext');

const username = context.get('username');
```

P.S. Keep in mind that in containerized environments where there can work many socket io instances in parallel it has to be done differently.

My example is for situations when You've unclustered 1 socket.io app instance.